# Why is volume of a gas in an open container assumed to be constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas, volume

I've read this in a book

> When air is heated in an open vessel, pressure is always atmospheric pressure, and volume of the gas is constant.

How is volume of the gas constant in this case?

Comment: Volume of a mass of gas, or volume of a container (the vessel)?

Comment: The quotation only makes sense if the writer is allowing the amount of gas to change. Either that or it is a mistake.

Comment: "The number of moles of gas can change if the temperature of gas is varied". I just want to know how is the volume constant.

Comment: An exotic way to say that the amount of gas changes.

Comment: Well some of the gas is no longer in the container, it's out of the container. The volume of gas in the container is the same because even though it expanded, some of it went out.

Answer (score 3):

When the container is open to atmosphere, gasses may exit or enter. This keeps the pressure inside equal to the pressure outside. this also keeps the volume of the gas inside the container the same unless the container itself expands or contracts. I believe that the statement should have been clearer on these points.

Comment: What is reasoning behind the fact that pressure will also remain same

Comment: @lalittolani The container is open. The air inside the open container is free to mix with the air outside of the container therefore it cannot have unconstrained higher pressure.

Answer (score 0):

The pressure and volume will be constant in an open container .
REASON : when the container is open the pressure inside the container and outside the container will be same . At the same time volume inside and outside the container will be same

Thanku

Comment: I agree with the first part of your answer. But, how can you say that the volume inside and outside the container are the same?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the volume occupied by a gas is the volume of free space available for it to move freely.
When we open the vessel which contains the gas, some gas molecules escape due to more availability of free space and their random motion.
Not all gas molecules escape due to the small difference in pressure inside the vessel and outside the vessel....Some stay within the container
The molecules that stay within the container occupy the entire container(like when the vessel was closed)
That's why we say volume of the gas is constant

Answer (score 0):

The volume of gas in an open container is the volume of the container itself. But volume can change if the container is expanding or contracting(if given in the question else let it be constant).... The pressure of the gas(in an open vessel) is equal to the surrounding atmospheric pressure as gases may exit or enter the container, so). *This* meanwhile need not be constant as it changes with the weather.

But considering you're studying for competitive exams or school, then assume that pressure and volume will be constant!